# command -v custom output

Tags: bash

I currently have the command:

```
command -v gpg 2>/dev/null || { echo "Cound not find gpg. Aborting."; }
```

I'd like for instead of it redirecting the output to /dev/null, I'd like to display a message stating the output of the command and afterwords `found!`.

I.e.

- If gpg is not found: `Cound not find gpg. Aborting.`
- If gpg is found: `gpg found at /usr/local/bin/gpg`

Comment: Why are you using the `{ }` group command there? It doesn't do anything useful in your example.

Comment: @Zanna You are actually correct. Overlooked that. It doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest approach would be something like this:

```
command -v gpg &>/dev/null && 
    echo "gpg found at  $(command -v gpg)" || 
    echo "Cound not find gpg. Aborting."
```

Of course that is not very elegant since it needs to run `command` twice. An alternative would be:

```
gpg=$(command -v gpg 2>/dev/null) && 
    echo "gpg found at $gpg." ||
    echo "Cound not find gpg. Aborting."
```

Comment: AFAIK, if command -v gpg doesn't find gpg, it won't output anything, so why discard error?

Comment: @SamuelSantana why not? Maybe a future implementation of `command` will print something to stderr. You have nothing to lose with the redirection and it might make it more robust. Also, consider a case where you try this on a shell that doesn't have `command`. I can't think of one where this syntax is valid, but there may be some out there. Just a case of better safe than sorry. Also, it's how the OP originally had it :)

Comment: @SamuelSantana why would I need to redirect differently? The 1st example is the non-portable, bash specific implementation of the OP's original. In bash, `&>/dev/null` is the same as `>/dev/null 2>&1`.

Answer (score 2):

This would do the trick:

```
command -v gpg &>/dev/null && echo "gpg has been found at $(which gpg)" || 
{ echo "Cound not find gpg. Aborting."; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Aliases may hide an executable's path, if you only care for the paths, you may do something like:

```
cmd_exists() {
  (
    unalias "$1" 2>/dev/null
    _status=$(command -v "$1")
    case $_status in
      *"$1") echo "$1 found at $_status";;
      "") echo "Could not find $1. Aborting."; return 127;;
    esac
  )
}

cmd_exists gpg
```